# rendering hircharchic structure in symfony

Tags: database, symfony, loops

I have a datastructure which has a (possible) infinite depth. Similar to a file structure. Now I'm thinking about the best solution to output this by a twig template.

I was thinking about passing a multidimensional array to twig but this isn'T the best solution I think.

The structure look like:

```
- id1|testname
- - id4|anothere one
- - - id12|onemore
- id42|another text
- - id48|anothernode
```

... and so on ...

Is there a good solution to grab all levels inside a controller?

Actually, I take all "level 0" nodes (the one without subnode -Ids) by a query and run through it by a for loop. Then I check in another function ($this->checkChildNodes($id)) if there are Child nodes existing. But this is really ...uhm... non-professionell and I need your help to get a clear and nice solution. 
Thank you all for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The way your query depends on the way you store the data structure in a database. Nested structures are much easier to query if you use solutions like a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) or [materialised path](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/).

In templates, you can leverage twig [blocks](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/block.html) or [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) to make rendering a bit easier.

I'd consider restricting depth level. Almost every time you can define a safe limit. I never had a requirement for an inifite nesting presented on a single view - it would be hard to present such a structure to the end user.

Also, have a look at how it's organised in [KnpMenu](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu) and [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle). [KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) looks interesting as well.

Comment: Thank you for the informatons. they are very interesting but in my case, it's abit tricky for the reason that I have to use the given db structure. in my case, I can only use the id and the parentNodeId. ech child got the ID of the parent element as a parentNodeId.... this makes it no really easy :(